# Want to merge two dataframe column wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes `df` and `df1` and I want to merge them in such way that I get result as showcased below.
I have tried using `pd.concat` but it didn't work out. While using `pd.merge` I get error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

```
    df
```

[image: df1]

```
df2
```

[image: df2]

Expected Output:[image]

Comment: the column names in the expected output are not matching the df andf df2

Comment: Please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead. And add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because the columns that you want to merge are not the same dtype. In pd.merge specify which columns who want to join on, and check using df.dtypes and df2.dtypes to see if the columns you want to join are the same dtypes.

Comment: can you show how you used pd.merge?

Comment: df has all columns as objects while df2 has two columns as objects and one column as float

Comment: Could you show you use would use the pd.merge function? for example, df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')